# python compare string in mukltiple rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have excel sheet in that I have 2 columns.

1st column has string .This string need to be compared with 2nd column's same row.If it matches need to write 'match' in 3rd column of same row.

If it wont match I need to iterate over the all the rows in excel till the end.
If it found in between need to write 'MATCH' otherwise I need to write 'Not Match'

I am using openpyxl to do this.

Comment: Show your code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to compare the columns with an if-statement and then write the output ('match'/'No match') to the third column. This could be done with the following example code:

```
    for index1, cell_col1 in enumerate(ws.columns[0]): # iterates through column 1 with indexing
        for index2, cell_col2 in enumerate(ws.columns[1]): # iterates through column 2 with indexing
            if cell_col1.value == cell_col2.value: # if the values match
                ws.cell(row=index1 + 1, column=3).value = 'Match'
                break
            elif index2 == ws.max_row - 1: # if the second loop is at the end of the table (so no match)
                ws.cell(row=index1 + 1, column=3).value = 'No match'
```

Comment: Thanks Frame for the reply.Actually If it is not match I need to iterate through next  rows till the end of all rows.If it is not found till the end then only I need to write 'no match'.I am struggling here .It would be helpful if u suggest any method to do this.I mean to say I need to improve the else case in above.Since I am new to python.I m not getting any logic to do this

Comment: Then you would have to generate some kind of array.
Please explain again, in detail, what the script should do exactly

Comment: I have txt file from which  I am extracting data and exporting to excel using enumerate function.Here it is making 2 columns in excel .I am able to do this successfully.Next step is I need to compare the col1 data with col2 .In col1 for every row there is some string that I need to check weather that string is present in the current row of col2 or not.If it not there is col2 then I need to iterate through next rows till the end of all rows.After comparing one row in col1 then I need to do it for next next rows in col1.Like this I need to do it for all the rows of col1 comparison with col2 rows

Comment: its like searching multiple strings one by one with the all the rows of another column. eg:col1 has strings  'abc','def','ghi','jkl' etc.I need to find weather 'abc' is present in any row of col2 or not,After 'abc' i need to compare 'def' with all the rows of col2 then 'ghi'  like this cycle will continue for all the rows of col1.

Comment: I have adapted the code and tested it. It worked on my test-file